# Am i allowed to style google streetview controls?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

It's prohibited to remove/change/cover google credentials - that's clear.
What about google streetview controls? Their documentation says we allowed to style them, but what they mean under "style"? Changing its position (TOP_RIGHT/LEFT_BITTON etc.) or appearance?

I want to make them light (dark by default) and align into one line (even when positioned in one place zoom in/out and fullscreen icons not on the same line)

Comment: HTML-wise, styling can affect positioning as well as appearance, if they wanted to prohibit specifically one of those 2, there would be a precise mention against it, not a vague term. You can go for both IMHO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use/service) not coding.

Comment: @geocodezip sit and vote ) Who did tell you that only coding problems discussions are allowed here?

Comment: [This tag should not be legal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) among others.